# Rails 3.2 Action Mailer return html of view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, mailchimp

I am building a newletter management tool for my rails app, and integrating it with Mailchimp (via the mandrill gem). I'd like to use ActionMailer to render the views of the newsletter, but instead of delivering it, I'd just like to have ActionMailer return the generated html to me so that I can pass it to mailchimp. Is there a method for doing so?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see Mandrill's recommendation on setup for Rails? http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks

Comment: @rossta yes i saw it. I don't want to deliver the mail from the app though, i want to use mailchimps api to create a new campaign using html i have generated from actionmailer, then use mailchimp to send the actual newsletter.